# non test functions inside phpunit and selenium2

Tags: php, function, selenium, phpunit

I got a function I want to be able to call from different functions in my selenium test. lets say it looks something like this:

```
class TestMyTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase {


    public function setUp()
    {
    $this->setHost('localhost');
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setBrowser("chrome");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    }


    public function foo()
    {
    $foo = array("foo", "bar", "foo_bar","bar_foo")
    return $foo;
    }

    public function testSelenium()
    {       
    var_dump(asd());
    }
}
```

I get undefined function foo when I run this. All my functions must start with the name test or they get undefined, is this just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so I solved this, the only thing I needed was adding $this-> like so
    `var_dump($this->asd());`